Can we use Density Functional Theory (DFT) to calculate the second and third-order force constants of a slab?
If we aim to compute the surface phonon lifetime of a Cu(111) surface, the second and third-order force constants are essential (to put in Boltzmann transport equation). However, to my knowledge, it seems that no one has performed such calculations before. Theoretically speaking, is it possible to compute the third-order force constant matrix of a slab using DFT?
Edit: It seems that calculations for 2D materials have already been performed by many people. From certain perspectives, 2D materials and surface systems (slabs) are quite similar in terms of DFT modelling. However, their phonon modes can be very different, for example, the Rayleigh mode exists only in surface systems.
I am wondering if it might be possible to apply the methods used for 2D materials to surface systems by simply adding a few more layers.

I could be wrong but I think phonopy and its related phon3py package can do this?

ShengBTE and almaBTE can do this. People may not have done it for a Cu slab, but there is plenty of literature for other systems.

This is often studied in the context of heat transport; third-order constants are required for thermal conductivities. As suggested above, there are codes to try this, another one if I recall correctly is dynasor https://dynasor.materialsmodeling.org/ .

Hi @PhilHasnip. Thank you for your reply. It seems that calculations for 2D materials and bulk systems have already been performed by lots of people. However, to my knowledge, no one has yet conducted similar studies on surface systems like the Cu(111) slab. I am wondering if it might be possible to apply the methods used for 2D materials to surface systems by simply adding a few more layers.

Hi @TristanMaxson, thank you for your comment. Yes many people have used phonopy and phon3py for bulk and 2D materials systems. However, to my knowledge, these tools have not been applied to surface models.

https://hiphive.materialsmodeling.org could be useful for higher order force constant

The third-order force constant tensor is simply a third derivative of the total energy $E$ with respect to all possible combinations of three atomic displacements $\{R_i\}$, i.e.
$$\tag{1}
\frac{\partial ^3 E}{\partial R_\alpha \partial R_\beta \partial R_\gamma}
$$
where for concision I've used compound indices $\alpha, \beta$ and $\gamma$,  which label both which atom is being displaced, and in which direction they are displaced. (I have also omitted the perturbation wavevector.)
This tensor is computable via density-functional perturbation theory (DFPT) in principle, but whilst most software packages will have good second-order DFPT capabilities, third-order DFPT properties are less widely implemented. (This is particularly true for more complicated simulation types, such as using ultrasoft or PAW pseudopotentials, or non-local exchange-correlation functionals). If you want to use DFPT, ABINIT is probably the best choice here for a periodic system.
An alternative to DFPT is direct numerical calculation, by literally displacing the atoms and recomputing the ground state. Since virtually all software packages have good force calculations implemented, and the force is
$$
-\frac{\partial E}{\partial R_\alpha},\tag{2}
$$
this is most commonly implemented by displacing atoms in only two independent directions, $R_\beta$ and $R_\gamma$, and comparing the change in forces. Both the short-range nature of the force-constant tensor and any symmetries of the structure can be exploited to reduce the number of displacements needed enormously.
Note that at no point does the dimensionality of the system affect anything, and this approach is applicable to any systems.
There are many software packages to generate displaced geometries for you, and to parse the results and compute the force constant tensors. The most widely-used options are probably:

ShengBTE (via the "third_order" Python script) and its successor almaBTE
phono3py

both of which support many DFT packages natively, such as CASTEP, Quantum Espresso and VASP. More recent options include Phoebe (phoebe.readthedocs.io), but I haven't used that personally.

"Since virtually all software packages have good force calculations implemented" let's meditate on that :)
